# Ubuntu can't communicate between two servers

Tags: ubuntu, networking, mongodb, static-routes, sysadmin

I have 3 servers:

- Server #1 runs among other things a MongoDB database
- Server #2 runs some apps that connect to server #1's mongodb, everything works fine
- Server #3 is a new server where more apps will connect to server #1's mongodb

My issue is with server #3, i am trying to get the app to connect to server #1's mongo without success. I've been looking at server #2 for reference and trying to replicate the configs there but somehow it seems i am missing something.

initially i noticed the firewall was up so not even incoming HTTP traffic was allowed, so i disabled UFW:

```
sudo ufw disable
sudo ufw status verbose

Status: inactive
```

Then i noticed that there was no route to reach server #1, which has an LAN IP of `10.100.116.65`, as i couldn't ping it:

```
sudo route -n

Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         [GATEWAY-IP]    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 enp1s0f0
[SERVER-IP]     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.248 U     0      0        0 enp1s0f0
```

I tried to add the route but the device was "not up":

```
sudo ip route add 10.100.116.0/24 via 0.0.0.0 dev enp1s0f1
Error: Device for nexthop is not up.
```

So i checked:

```
ip link show

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp1s0f0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 0c:c4:7a:18:64:58 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: enp1s0f1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 0c:c4:7a:18:64:59 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Then upped it:

```
sudo ifconfig enp1s0f1 up

ip link show

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp1s0f0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 0c:c4:7a:18:64:58 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: enp1s0f1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 0c:c4:7a:18:64:59 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Now that it's up, i added a route to reach server #1:

```
sudo ip route add 10.100.116.0/24 via 0.0.0.0 dev enp1s0f1

sudo route -n

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         [GATEWAY-IP]    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 enp1s0f0
10.100.116.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp1s0f1
[SERVER-IP]     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.248 U     0      0        0 enp1s0f0
```

But i still couldn't ping server #1:

```
ping 10.100.116.65

PING 10.100.116.65 (10.100.116.65) 56(84) bytes of data.
From X.X.X.X icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From X.X.X.X icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From X.X.X.X icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
From X.X.X.X icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable
^C
--- 10.100.116.65 ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 0 received, +4 errors, 100% packet loss, time 5102ms
```

I kept comparing Server #2's configs with server #3's and noticed that server #3 didn't have a LAN IP assigned yet for `enp1s0f1`:

```
 ifconfig
enp1s0f0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet X.X.X.X  netmask 255.255.255.248  broadcast X.X.X.X
        inet6 fe80::ec4:7aff:fe18:6458  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 0c:c4:7a:18:64:58  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 7470666  bytes 2108978738 (2.1 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 8563092  bytes 6460993288 (6.4 GB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device memory 0xe0000000-e007ffff  

enp1s0f1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::ec4:7aff:fe18:6459  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 0c:c4:7a:18:64:59  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 125640  bytes 25067378 (25.0 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1630  bytes 92016 (92.0 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device memory 0xe0080000-e00fffff  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 4317856  bytes 524128762 (524.1 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 4317856  bytes 524128762 (524.1 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

So i added one in the `netplan` file:

```
sudo pico /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml 

network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
   id0:
      match:
        macaddress: 0c:c4:7a:18:64:58
      addresses: [X.X.X.X/29]
      gateway4: X.X.X.X
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]

   # i added these 2 lines
   enp1s0f1:
      addresses: [ 10.100.116.62/24 ]
```

Then saved and applied with `sudo netplan apply`, confirmed with `ifconfig`:

```
ifconfig
enp1s0f0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet X.X.X.X  netmask 255.255.255.248  broadcast X.X.X.X
        inet6 fe80::ec4:7aff:fe18:6458  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 0c:c4:7a:18:64:58  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 7471402  bytes 2109059743 (2.1 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 8563748  bytes 6461111312 (6.4 GB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device memory 0xe0000000-e007ffff  

enp1s0f1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.100.116.62  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.100.116.255
        inet6 fe80::ec4:7aff:fe18:6459  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 0c:c4:7a:18:64:59  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 149491  bytes 29787304 (29.7 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1975  bytes 111102 (111.1 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device memory 0xe0080000-e00fffff  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 4331691  bytes 525564926 (525.5 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 4331691  bytes 525564926 (525.5 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Finally some success, i can now ping server #1:

```
ping 10.100.116.65

PING 10.100.116.65 (10.100.116.65) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.100.116.65: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.094 ms
64 bytes from 10.100.116.65: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.254 ms
64 bytes from 10.100.116.65: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.221 ms
64 bytes from 10.100.116.65: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.245 ms
64 bytes from 10.100.116.65: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.248 ms
^C
--- 10.100.116.65 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 4096ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.094/0.212/0.254/0.061 ms
```

And yet, event after restarting the app, it throws an error when trying to connect to server #1's mongo complaining there is no route to host:

```
MONGODB | Error checking 10.100.116.65:27017: Mongo::Error::SocketError: Errno::EHOSTUNREACH: No route to host - connect(2) for 10.100.116.65:27017 (for 10.100.116.65:27017 (no TLS)) (on 10.100.116.65:27017)
```

I've even rebooted the server just in case but that didn't help.

I'm a developer so i'm a bit clueless about all this so i'm probably missing something obvious but i have no idea what, can anybody shed some light on this?

**EDIT**

I've also looked at the `iptables` for server #1, it had a rule to accept traffic from server #2 so i also added the same rule for server #3:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -s 10.100.116.62/32 -m comment --comment server3 -j ACCEPT
```

i've also added a rule in server #3's iptables to accept traffic from server #1:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -s 10.100.116.65/32 -m comment --comment server1 -j ACCEPT
```

But i'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright so finally figure this out, turns out the `iptables` rules order matters and the last rule was to block all traffic so when i added in server #1 the rule to accept incoming traffic from server #3, i used `-A` which appends to the end of the list, instead, i had to delete it add it again using `-I` to insert it before the last rule that blocked all traffic, after that it worked.